# Changing an onEdit function to run onOpen

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have the function below (found online and adapted and it works) that is an on-edit function, but I want it to run/trigger when an import is done OR on open, as the data will not really be edited it will just be frequently overwritten by an import. Is this possible? Basically, col A values need to be formatted red depending on the values in a number of other columns and the only problem is that I’m not editing them.

Here's the code:

```
  function foramtName() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var r = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange(); 

    if (r.getRow() != 1 && ss.getName() == "e404") {

        // 4, 5, 6, 7 are cols D, E, F, G
        vm = ss.getRange(r.getRow(), 4).getValue();
        gg = ss.getRange(r.getRow(), 5).getValue();
        inter = ss.getRange(r.getRow(), 6).getValue();
        other = ss.getRange(r.getRow(), 7).getValue();

        rowRange = ss.getRange(r.getRow(),1,1,1);
        // sum of these need to equal zero to colour red
        if (vm == '0' && gg == '0' && inter == '0' && other == '0') {
          rowRange.setBackgroundColor("red");
        } else {
          rowRange.setBackgroundColor("white");
        }
      } //end upper if
    }
```

Like I said, I’m new, so I’m not entirely sure if the first 2 lines are allowed even though it runs, and I can’t help thinking there is a much simpler way to sum the 4 cols—D, E, F, G—to colour col A red.

Example file: [Row Color](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Amr3B3eEcFQ9dEZvTkJxSTdrQjN1Y1lsLVRPTXBpbnc&usp=sharing)

Comment: Why don't you share a doc with us, so that we can have a look....

Comment: You say sum, does this mean that this is possible as well: `D=1, E=-1, F=0, G=0`?

Comment: No there will never be negative numbers. Zero is the lowest and if all 4 cols are zero name will turn red. I will. Share a link to the sheet when i get home.

Comment: Here is a link to the spreadsheet with the function above
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Amr3B3eEcFQ9dEZvTkJxSTdrQjN1Y1lsLVRPTXBpbnc&usp=sharing

Comment: I've added the script to your file, plus added the menu option. See how it works on opening and when selecting the menu option !!

Comment: Well i dont really understand it, but yes it works brillient, Thank you for your time Jacob. If you have a second could you put a few comments in for future reference/development and learing Ty again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename your script to a normal function, something like `setColor`. Rewrite the script to contain all the proper references. After that, you can select the proper trigger in the script editor:

[image]

Select the `onOpen` trigger for the function.

The second this you can do, is to create a menu item in the active spreadsheet, like this:

```
var menu = [{name: "Set Color", functionName: "setColor"}];
ss.addMenu("Extra", menu);
```

If you add it to the existing script, it will be added on opening of the file. While your at it, use the following script:

```
function foramtName() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var mRows = ss.getMaxRows()-1, mCols = ss.getMaxColumns();
  var cRange = ss.getRange(2, 1, mRows, mCols);

  if (ss.getName() == "e404") {
    var aData = ss.getRange(2, 4, mRows, 4).getValues(); 
    var colors = new Array();    
    for(i in aData) {
      colors[i] = new Array();
      for(var j=0; j<mCols; j++) {
        if(aData[i].reduce(function(a, b) {return a + b}) === 0) {
          colors[i][j] = 'red';
        } else {
          colors[i][j] = 'white';
        }
      }       
    }
    cRange.setBackgrounds(colors);
  }
}
```

Comment: ok im really new to this. I think i understand the above and did try rewritting a couple of ways but was unsuccessful. Closest i got was the below. still looking at other scripts to try and integrate the code successfully: